# Tracing the request to the Server from an external IP

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

I'm running a game server on my Windows Server 2008 VPS. It uses ports 443 and 444.

Recently there are some suspicious activity from a user. I always have access to the users IP address. How to find out what requests are sent to these ports from that IP?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see packets that came in and goes out from you server you can install wireshark and capture all packets or filter them by specific ports.

Comment: Dear Max, I appreciate your help. I'll try it and let you know the result.